# Simplest example of backwards continuations in Scheme without explicit mutation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, scheme, continuations

I've written a small Scheme interpreter in C#, and realised that the way I had implemented it, it was very easy to add support for proper continuations.

So I added them... but want to "prove" that they way that I've added them is correct.

My Scheme interpreter however has no support for "mutating" state - everything is immutable.

So it was pretty easy to write a unit test to expose "upwards" continuations:

```
AssertEqual(Eval("(call/cc (lambda (k) (+ 56 (k 3))))"), 3);
```

However, I also want to write a unit test that demonstrates that if the continuation "escapes" then that still works too:

```
AssertEqual(Eval("(call/cc (lambda (k) k))", <some continuation>);
```

But of course, the above would just test that "I got a continuation"... not that it's actually a valid continuation.

All of the examples I can find, however, always end up using "set!" to demonstrate the escaped continuation.

What's the simplest Scheme example that demonstrates proper support for backwards continuations without relying on mutation?

Are backwards continuations any use without mutation? I am beginning to suspect that they are not, because you could only use it to execute the exact same calculation again... which is meaningless if there are no side-effects. Is this why Haskell does not have continuations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is the simplest, but here's an example of using backwards continuations without any call to `set!` or similar:

```
(apply
  (lambda (k i) (if (> i 5) i (k (list k (* 2 i)))))
  (call/cc (lambda (k) (list k 1))))
```

This should evaluate to `8`.

Slightly more interesting is:

```
(apply
  (lambda (k i n) (if (= i 0) n (k (list k (- i 1) (* i n)))))
  (call/cc (lambda (k) (list k 6 1))))
```

which computes `6!` (that is, it should evaluate to `720`).

You can even do the same thing with `let*`:

```
(let* ((ka (call/cc (lambda (k) `(,k 1)))) (k (car ka)) (a (cadr ka)))
      (if (< a 5) (k `(,k ,(* 2 a))) a))
```

(Man, stackoverflow's syntax highlighting fails massively on scheme.)

Comment: Hey that's neat! I think... I need to figure out what on earth it does now!!! ;-)

Comment: OK I get it now... That's very clever! And it demonstrates an actual use: looping without explicit recursion.

Comment: Right.  Of course, anyone familiar with the Y combinator will tell you that you don't need continuations for that, but maybe I can come up with something not quite as obvious.

Comment: yeah I found out all about Y combinator - in fact, one of my first test cases was a factorial that used a Y combinator. I'll have to try your example tomorrow to see if my interpreter works...

Comment: oh and just discovered that the two are very related indeed: http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Continuations.html#fix-callcc

Comment: You'll be glad to know, your test works!

        [Test]
        public void TestFactorialBackwardsCallCC()
        {
            // Thanks to Daniel Martin:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983776/simplest-example-of-backwards-continuations-in-scheme-without-explicit-mutation
            // Compute 6! without explicit recursion, rather using a continuation
            e.StackEval("(apply (lambda (k i n) (if (eq? i 0) n (k (list k (- i 1) (* i n))))) (call/cc (lambda (k) (list k 6 1))))",
                720);
        }

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right -- without mutation, backwards continuations do nothing that forward continuations can't.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I've come up with:

```
AssertEqual(Eval("((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) 5))", 5);
```

Not amazing, but it is a backwards continuation which I then "call" with the actual function I wish to invoke, a function that returns the number 5.

Ah and I've also come up with this as a good unit test case:

```
AssertEqual(Eval("((call/cc call/cc) (lambda (x) 5))", 5);
```

I agree with Jacob B - I don't think it's that useful without mutable state... but would be still be interested in a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

**Functional Threads:**

You can use a recursive loop to update state without mutation. including the state of the next continuation to be called. Now this is more complicated than the other examples given, but all you really need is the `thread-1` and `main` loop. The other thread and "update" function are there to show that continuations can be used for more than a trivial example. Additionally, for this example to work you need an implementation with the named let. This can be translated into an equivalent form made with define statements.

Example:

```
(let* ((update (lambda (data) data))                ;is identity to keep simple for example
       (thread-1                                    
         (lambda (cc)                               ;cc is the calling continuation
           (let loop ((cc cc)(state 0))
             (printf "--doing stuff       state:~A~N" state)
             (loop (call/cc cc)(+ state 1)))))      ;this is where the exit hapens
       (thread-2
         (lambda (data)                             ;returns the procedure to be used as 
           (lambda (cc)                             ;thread with data bound
             (let loop ((cc cc)(data data)(state 0))
               (printf "--doing other stuff state:~A~N" state)
               (loop (call/cc cc)(update data)(+ state 1)))))))
  (let main ((cur thread-1)(idle (thread-2 '()))(state 0))
    (printf "doing main stuff    state:~A~N" state)
    (if (< state 6)
        (main (call/cc idle) cur (+ state 1)))))
```

Which outputs

```
doing main stuff    state:0
--doing other stuff state:0
doing main stuff    state:1
--doing stuff       state:0
doing main stuff    state:2
--doing other stuff state:1
doing main stuff    state:3
--doing stuff       state:1
doing main stuff    state:4
--doing other stuff state:2
doing main stuff    state:5
--doing stuff       state:2
doing main stuff    state:6
```